# Restore Ubuntu 16.04 which was corrupted by sudo apt autoremove python3

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, rescue-mode

I mistakenly ran the command, `sudo apt autoremove python3` in Ubuntu 16.04. Because of that all software was removed, and even the terminal is not working. Debian package manager is also not working. I'm unable to reinstall the terminal application from a .deb file.

The following packages were removed by `sudo apt autoremove python3`:

> Remove: gkbd-capplet:i386 (3.6.0-1ubuntu2), python-gnome2:i386 (2.28.1+dfsg-1.1), python3-pexpect:i386 (4.0.1-1), libframe6:i386 (2.5.0daily13.06.05+16.04.20160809-0ubuntu1), qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), gnome-flashback-common:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu1), python3-defer:i386 (1.0.6-2build1), gir1.2-gdata-0.0:i386 (0.17.4-1), python3-dev:i386 (3.5.1-3), hplip-data:i386 (3.16.3+repack0-1), suru-icon-theme:i386 (14.04+16.04.20180326-0ubuntu1), unity-lens-music:i386 (6.9.1+16.04-0ubuntu1), python3-html5lib:i386 (0.999-4), fonts-lyx:i386 (2.1.4-2), libglade2-0:i386 (1:2.6.4-2), python3-cupshelpers:i386 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2), libgksu2-0:i386 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu8), python-blinker:i386 (1.3.dfsg2-1build1), python3-piston-mini-client:i386 (0.7.5-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1:i386 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1), unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1), lybniz:i386 (1.3.2-2.1), libgtkspell0:i386 (2.0.16-1.1ubuntu1), python-xapian:i386 (1.2.22-2build1), gir1.2-gudev-1.0:i386 (1:230-2), libges-1.0-0:i386 (1.6.2-1), libimage-magick-perl:i386 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13), jayatana:i386 (2.7-0ubuntu5), libart-2.0-2:i386 (2.3.21-2), python-debtagshw:i386 (2.0.1ubuntu6), gnome-applets-data:i386 (3.18.2-1), unity-schemas:i386 (7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), update-manager-core:i386 (1:16.04.15), libgnomecanvas2-common:i386 (2.30.3-2), libnux-4.0-common:i386 (4.0.8+16.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1), unity-control-center-faces:i386 (15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1), gedit:i386 (3.18.3-0ubuntu4), qml-module-ubuntu-test:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), libgnome2-bin:i386 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1), libgnomeui-0:i386 (2.24.5-3.1), libxapian-1.3-5:i386 (1.3.4-0ubuntu6), dia-shapes:i386 (0.6.0-1), gir1.2-gmenu-3.0:i386 (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1), compiz-plugins-default:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), python3-dateutil:i386 (2.4.2-1), unity-scope-virtualbox:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), dc:i386 (1.06.95-9build1), software-center-aptdaemon-plugins:i386 (0.1.6build1), libdbus2.0-cil:i386 (0.8.1-2), liblist-moreutils-perl:i386 (0.413-1build1), libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), tomboy:i386 (1.15.4-0ubuntu3), python3-mako:i386 (1.0.3+ds1-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-secret-1:i386 (0.18.4-1ubuntu2), libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 (1.2.0-8), mscompress:i386 (0.4-3), libgsoap8:i386 (2.8.28-1), libcolumbus1v5:i386 (1.1.0+15.10.20150806-0ubuntu4), python3-software-properties:i386 (0.96.20.7), extlinux:i386 (3:6.03+dfsg-11ubuntu1), python3-bsddb3:i386 (6.1.0-1build2), python3-icu:i386 (1.9.2-2build1), libimage-magick-q16-perl:i386 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13), apt-xapian-index:i386 (0.47ubuntu8.4), bamfdaemon:i386 (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1), appstream:i386 (0.9.4-1ubuntu4), intltool-debian:i386 (0.35.0+20060710.4), foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:i386 (20160212-0ubuntu1), python3-xkit:i386 (0.5.0ubuntu2), libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), update-notifier-common:i386 (3.168.9), edubuntu-desktop:i386 (15.12.5), unity-webapps-common:i386 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), apturl-common:i386 (0.5.2ubuntu11.2), python3-jwt:i386 (1.3.0-1ubuntu0.1), libdecoration0:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), libindicator7:i386 (12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1), libarchive-zip-perl:i386 (1.56-2ubuntu0.1), onboard:i386 (1.2.0-0ubuntu5), libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), libexpat1-dev:i386 (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.3), apg:i386 (2.2.3.dfsg.1-2ubuntu1), cups-pk-helper:i386 (0.2.5-2ubuntu2), libasprintf-dev:i386 (0.19.7-2ubuntu3), python3-systemd:i386 (231-2build1), libtimezonemap1:i386 (0.4.5), ubuntu-system-service:i386 (0.3), gir1.2-osmgpsmap-1.0:i386 (1.1.0-1), snapd:i386 (2.34.2), pastebinit:i386 (1.5-1), printer-driver-foo2zjs:i386 (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-ges-1.0:i386 (1.6.2-1), update-manager:i386 (1:16.04.15), printer-driver-postscript-hp:i386 (3.16.3+repack0-1), libemail-valid-perl:i386 (1.198-1), python3-urllib3:i386 (1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.2), gir1.2-keybinder-3.0:i386 (0.3.1-1), libqt5organizer5:i386 (5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu20), python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), language-selector-common:i386 (0.165.4), libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), python3-reportlab-accel:i386 (3.3.0-1), dia:i386 (0.97.3-1), unetbootin:i386 (608-1), libcgi-fast-perl:i386 (1:2.10-1), libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil:i386 (1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-4), libqmi-glib1:i386 (1.12.6-1), libidl-2-0:i386 (0.8.14-4), python3-gi-cairo:i386 (3.20.0-0ubuntu1), intel-gpu-tools:i386 (1.14-1), gnome-software:i386 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), dia-gnome:i386 (0.97.3-1), libexporter-tiny-perl:i386 (0.042-1), gdebi-core:i386 (0.9.5.7ubuntu1), unity-lens-applications:i386 (7.1.0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1), patchutils:i386 (0.3.4-1), usb-creator-common:i386 (0.3.2), libfcgi-perl:i386 (0.77-1build1), python3-pyqt5:i386 (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4), ubuntu-standard:i386 (1.361.2), libgettextpo0:i386 (0.19.7-2ubuntu3), python3-brlapi:i386 (5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1), python3-pil:i386 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1), python3-pip:i386 (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4), unity-scope-video-remote:i386 (0.3.15+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1), libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts:i386 (0.6+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1), libcgi-pm-perl:i386 (4.26-1), python3-wheel:i386 (0.29.0-1), gnome-orca:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu3), libgmime2.6-cil:i386 (2.6.20-1), plainbox-provider-resource-generic:i386 (0.23-1), gir1.2-unity-5.0:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), libnet-dns-perl:i386 (0.81-2build1), ubuntu-desktop:i386 (1.361.2), python-matplotlib-data:i386 (1.5.1-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10:i386 (0.10.3-2), python3:i386 (3.5.1-3), python3-pyatspi:i386 (2.18.0+dfsg-3), libtext-levenshtein-perl:i386 (0.13-1), libperlio-gzip-perl:i386 (0.19-1build1), python3-louis:i386 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.4), xdiagnose:i386 (3.8.4.1), libzeitgeist-1.0-1:i386 (0.3.18-1ubuntu3), virtualbox-dkms:i386 (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1), python3-idna:i386 (2.0-3), printer-driver-pxljr:i386 (1.4+repack0-4), qml-module-qttest:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), xbrlapi:i386 (5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1), unity-scope-manpages:i386 (3.0+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1), libmono-system-data4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), unity-scopes-runner:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), python3-matplotlib:i386 (1.5.1-1ubuntu1), libappindicator0.1-cil:i386 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1), unity-scope-colourlovers:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), usb-creator-gtk:i386 (0.3.2), python-oneconf:i386 (0.3.9), libbonobo2-common:i386 (2.32.1-3), hud:i386 (14.10+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1), rhythmbox-plugins:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:i386 (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5), libmono-ldap4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), python3-sip:i386 (4.17+dfsg-1build1), python3-six:i386 (1.10.0-3), dia-common:i386 (0.97.3-1), unity:i386 (7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), gnome-subtitles:i386 (1.3-2), libmono-data-tds4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), qmlscene:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), unity-scope-zotero:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), python3.5-dev:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), unity-lens-photos:i386 (1.0+14.04.20140318-0ubuntu1), command-not-found-data:i386 (0.3ubuntu16.04.2), gnome-panel-data:i386 (1:3.18.3-0ubuntu0.1), python3-numpy:i386 (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1), oneconf:i386 (0.3.9), gdebi:i386 (0.9.5.7ubuntu1), libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386 (16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1), software-properties-gtk:i386 (0.96.20.7), dkms:i386 (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.5), gramps:i386 (4.2.2~dfsg-1), python3-uno:i386 (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial4), python3-cycler:i386 (0.9.0-1), virtualbox:i386 (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1), unity-scope-gdrive:i386 (0.9+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1), libnux-4.0-0:i386 (4.0.8+16.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1), libbonoboui2-common:i386 (2.24.5-3ubuntu1), python3-requests:i386 (2.9.1-3ubuntu0.1), libgpod4:i386 (0.8.3-6ubuntu2), libunity-action-qt1:i386 (1.1.0+14.04.20140304-0ubuntu2~gcc5.1), qml-module-qt-labs-settings:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), python3-httplib2:i386 (0.9.1+dfsg-1), unity-scope-yelp:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), qtdeclarative5-test-plugin:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), libglade2.0-cil:i386 (2.12.10-6), python3-plainbox:i386 (0.25-1), libunity-gtk2-parser0:i386 (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2), checkbox-converged:i386 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1), python3-cups:i386 (1.9.73-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0:i386 (3.10.6-1ubuntu1), unity-control-center:i386 (15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1), libgettextpo-dev:i386 (0.19.7-2ubuntu3), libqt5quicktest5:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), python3-pyparsing:i386 (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1), python3-xlsxwriter:i386 (0.7.3-1), python3-xapian1.3:i386 (1.3.4-0ubuntu1), libapt-pkg-perl:i386 (0.1.29build7), python3-renderpm:i386 (3.3.0-1), qml-module-ubuntu-web:i386 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader:i386 (1.16.0-1ubuntu2), apturl:i386 (0.5.2ubuntu11.2), python3-xdg:i386 (0.25-4), gir1.2-rb-3.0:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), python3-pycurl:i386 (7.43.0-1ubuntu1), libgeis1:i386 (2.2.17+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1), aisleriot:i386 (1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1), libbamf3-2:i386 (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-signon-1.0:i386 (1.13+16.04.20151209.1-0ubuntu1), rhythmbox-data:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), ubuntu-minimal:i386 (1.361.1), apport:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18), libgdm1:i386 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2.2), rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), nautilus-share:i386 (0.7.3-2ubuntu1), qml-module-qtfeedback:i386 (5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu13), alacarte:i386 (3.11.91-2), libx86-1:i386 (1.1+ds1-10), webapp-container:i386 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), unity-webapps-service:i386 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), unity-gtk-module-common:i386 (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2), unity-lens-video:i386 (0.3.15+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-drivers-common:i386 (1:0.4.17.7), python3-speechd:i386 (0.8.3-1ubuntu3), libclone-perl:i386 (0.38-1build1), libapparmor-perl:i386 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.10), gir1.2-wnck-3.0:i386 (3.14.1-2), libsub-name-perl:i386 (0.14-1build1), python3-cryptography:i386 (1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1), python3-distupgrade:i386 (1:16.04.25), gksu:i386 (2.0.2-9ubuntu1), unity-scope-home:i386 (6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1), libgnomeui-common:i386 (2.24.5-3.1), python3-commandnotfound:i386 (0.3ubuntu16.04.2), ubuntu-software:i386 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), gir1.2-vte-2.91:i386 (0.42.5-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-gtksource-3.0:i386 (3.18.2-1), python3-update-manager:i386 (1:16.04.15), libmono-system-web4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), libmono-system-design4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), libgnome2-0:i386 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1), libhud2:i386 (14.10+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:i386 (1:16.04.25), python3-apport:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18), unity-gtk2-module:i386 (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2), hplip:i386 (3.16.3+repack0-1), python-defer:i386 (1.0.6-2build1), system-config-printer-gnome:i386 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2), python3-cffi-backend:i386 (1.5.2-1ubuntu1), guile-2.0-libs:i386 (2.0.11+1-10ubuntu0.1), libosmgpsmap-1.0-1:i386 (1.1.0-1), libunity-gtk3-parser0:i386 (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2), python-oauthlib:i386 (1.0.3-1), unity-scope-openclipart:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), libgpod-common:i386 (0.8.3-6ubuntu2), libcolumbus1-common:i386 (1.1.0+15.10.20150806-0ubuntu4), plainbox-provider-checkbox:i386 (0.25-1), gnome-panel:i386 (1:3.18.3-0ubuntu0.1), unity-scope-calculator:i386 (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1), python-debian:i386 (0.1.27ubuntu2), unity-services:i386 (7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), appmenu-qt:i386 (0.2.7+14.04.20140305-0ubuntu2), indicator-bluetooth:i386 (0.0.6+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-udisks-2.0:i386 (2.1.7-1ubuntu1), session-shortcuts:i386 (1.2ubuntu0.16.04.1), libunity-core-6.0-9:i386 (7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), python3-markupsafe:i386 (0.23-2build2), ufw:i386 (0.35-0ubuntu2), lintian:i386 (2.5.43ubuntu0.1), ibus-table:i386 (1.9.1-3ubuntu2), libmono-addins0.2-cil:i386 (1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-4), python3-blinker:i386 (1.3.dfsg2-1build1), unity-control-center-signon:i386 (0.1.8+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), inkscape:i386 (0.91-7ubuntu2), checkbox-gui:i386 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1), kazam:i386 (1.5.3-0ubuntu3), libjs-jquery-ui:i386 (1.10.1+dfsg-1), system-config-printer-udev:i386 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2), syslinux:i386 (3:6.03+dfsg-11ubuntu1), gedit-common:i386 (3.18.3-0ubuntu4), python-twisted-web:i386 (16.0.0-1ubuntu0.2), python3-pkg-resources:i386 (20.7.0-1), compiz-gnome:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), libyaml-libyaml-perl:i386 (0.41-6build1), qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin:i386 (1.1.0+14.04.20140304-0ubuntu2~gcc5.1), libdbus-glib2.0-cil:i386 (0.6.0-1build1), vbetool:i386 (1.1-3), gir1.2-goa-1.0:i386 (3.18.3-1ubuntu2), appmenu-qt5:i386 (0.3.0+16.04.20170216-0ubuntu1), libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), libpython3.5-dev:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), libgnome-2-0:i386 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1), pm-utils:i386 (1.4.1-16), python3-guacamole:i386 (0.9.2-1), dh-python:i386 (2.20151103ubuntu1.1), openprinting-ppds:i386 (20160212-0ubuntu1), libgsettings-qt1:i386 (0.1+16.04.20160329-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-atspi-2.0:i386 (2.18.3-4ubuntu1), gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:i386 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2), ubuntu-mobile-icons:i386 (14.04+16.04.20180326-0ubuntu1), qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), totem-plugins:i386 (3.18.1-1ubuntu4), libappindicator1:i386 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1), python3-gst-1.0:i386 (1.6.2-1build1), libcompizconfig0:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), python-pyorbit:i386 (2.24.0-7.1), python-aptdaemon:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), libio-string-perl:i386 (1.08-3), libio-pty-perl:i386 (1:1.08-1.1build1), gir1.2-totem-1.0:i386 (3.18.1-1ubuntu4), pitivi:i386 (0.95-1), compiz:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), dia-libs:i386 (0.97.3-1), qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside:i386 (1.4.0-2), libbonoboui2-0:i386 (2.24.5-3ubuntu1), libgnome-menu-3-0:i386 (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1), python-dirspec:i386 (13.10-1ubuntu1), aptdaemon-data:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4:i386 (16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1), libglewmx1.13:i386 (1.13.0-2), python3-dbus:i386 (1.2.0-3), libsane-hpaio:i386 (3.16.3+repack0-1), syslinux-legacy:i386 (2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu8), libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), gnome-applets:i386 (3.18.2-1), software-center:i386 (16.01+16.04.20160420), python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), libunity-misc4:i386 (4.0.5+14.04.20140115-0ubuntu1), ibus:i386 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.1), python3-cairo:i386 (1.10.0+dfsg-5build1), python3-aptdaemon:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), lsb-release:i386 (9.20160110ubuntu0.2), apport-gtk:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:i386 (1:16.04.25), libgnomevfs2-common:i386 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1), python3-multibootusb:i386 (9.2.0-1), hardening-includes:i386 (2.7ubuntu2), python3-gi:i386 (3.20.0-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-accounts-1.0:i386 (1.21+16.04.20160222-0ubuntu1), libdata-alias-perl:i386 (1.20-1build1), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:i386 (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.4), libnet-domain-tld-perl:i386 (1.73-1), python3-tk:i386 (3.5.1-1), python3-tz:i386 (2014.10~dfsg1-0ubuntu2), gnome-flashback:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:i386 (2.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), qml-module-ubuntu-components:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), gnome-terminal-data:i386 (3.18.3-1ubuntu1), python3-ptyprocess:i386 (0.5-1), unattended-upgrades:i386 (0.90ubuntu0.9), python-gconf:i386 (2.28.1+dfsg-1.1), virtualbox-qt:i386 (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1), gir1.2-ibus-1.0:i386 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.1), python3-oauthlib:i386 (1.0.3-1), firefox:i386 (63.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), libsgutils2-2:i386 (1.40-0ubuntu1), snapd-login-service:i386 (1.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), unetbootin-translations:i386 (608-1), apparmor:i386 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.10), command-not-found:i386 (0.3ubuntu16.04.2), libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:i386 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13), qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin:i386 (0.6+16.04.20151106-0ubuntu1), libgc1c2:i386 (1:7.4.2-7.3ubuntu0.1), gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:i386 (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1), indicator-appmenu:i386 (15.02.0+16.04.20151104-0ubuntu1), avahi-utils:i386 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2), ubuntu-sso-client:i386 (13.10-0ubuntu11), libubuntutoolkit5:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), libappstream3:i386 (0.9.4-1ubuntu4), python-jwt:i386 (1.3.0-1ubuntu0.1), libtimezonemap-data:i386 (0.4.5), libdmapsharing-3.0-2:i386 (2.9.34-1), libsnapd-glib1:i386 (1.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgrail6:i386 (3.1.0+16.04.20160125-0ubuntu1), aptdaemon:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), libpython3-dev:i386 (3.5.1-3), gir1.2-json-1.0:i386 (1.1.2-0ubuntu1), libgnomevfs2-0:i386 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1), signon-keyring-extension:i386 (0.6+14.10.20140513-0ubuntu2), python3-jinja2:i386 (2.8-1), python-ubuntu-sso-client:i386 (13.10-0ubuntu11), unity-scope-tomboy:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), python3-checkbox-support:i386 (0.22-1), liborbit2:i386 (1:2.14.19-1build1), language-selector-gnome:i386 (0.165.4), libgnomekbd8:i386 (3.6.0-1ubuntu2), system-config-printer-common:i386 (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2), webbrowser-app:i386 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), app-install-data:i386 (15.10), compiz-core:i386 (1:0.9.12.3+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1), apport-symptoms:i386 (0.20), python3-reportlab:i386 (3.3.0-1), gettext:i386 (0.19.7-2ubuntu3), syslinux-common:i386 (3:6.03+dfsg-11ubuntu1), unity-scopes-master-default:i386 (6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1), liborbit-2-0:i386 (1:2.14.19-1build1), python3-debian:i386 (0.1.27ubuntu2), printer-driver-ptouch:i386 (1.4-1), libipc-run-perl:i386 (0.94-1), libubuntugestures5:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), onboard-data:i386 (1.2.0-0ubuntu5), python3-lxml:i386 (3.5.0-1build1), python3-pyudev:i386 (0.16.1-3), libgnomecanvas2-0:i386 (2.30.3-2), python3-gdbm:i386 (3.5.1-1), libprotobuf9v5:i386 (2.6.1-1.3), gnome-terminal:i386 (3.18.3-1ubuntu1), unity-scope-texdoc:i386 (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1), unity-scope-devhelp:i386 (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1), libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme:i386 (1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1), unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks:i386 (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-panelapplet-5.0:i386 (1:3.18.3-0ubuntu0.1), qtdeclarative5-dev-tools:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), gnome-software-common:i386 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), libbonobo2-0:i386 (2.32.1-3), sessioninstaller:i386 (0.20+bzr150-0ubuntu4.1), libclass-accessor-perl:i386 (0.34-1), libgeonames0:i386 (0.2+16.04.20160321-0ubuntu1), python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:i386 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14), nux-tools:i386 (4.0.8+16.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1), libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), python3-padme:i386 (1.1.1-2), python3-oneconf:i386 (0.3.9), update-notifier:i386 (3.168.9), python3-chardet:i386 (2.3.0-2), gnome-session-flashback:i386 (1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1), python3-problem-report:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18), libcpufreq0:i386 (008-1), python-pip-whl:i386 (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4), python-cups:i386 (1.9.73-0ubuntu2), libunity-webapps0:i386 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), libgtkspell3-3-0:i386 (3.0.7-2), gconf2:i386 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6), unity-gtk3-module:i386 (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2), libnet-ip-perl:i386 (1.26-1), libgnome2-common:i386 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1), libmono-sqlite4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), oneconf-common:i386 (0.3.9), printer-driver-foo2zjs-common:i386 (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-dee-1.0:i386 (1.2.7+15.04.20150304-0ubuntu2), qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:i386 (5.5.1-1ubuntu1), python3-apt:i386 (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2), unity-lens-files:i386 (7.1.0+16.04.20151217-0ubuntu1), libmono-accessibility4.0-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), python3-setuptools:i386 (20.7.0-1), libgnomevfs2-extra:i386 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1), rhythmbox:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), ippusbxd:i386 (1.23-1), diffstat:i386 (1.61-1), qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin:i386 (5.5.1-2ubuntu6), unity-webapps-qml:i386 (0.1+16.04.20160114-0ubuntu1), pyotherside:i386 (1.4.0-2), librhythmbox-core9:i386 (3.3-1ubuntu7), python3-bs4:i386 (4.4.1-1), python3-pyasn1:i386 (0.1.9-1), plainbox-secure-policy:i386 (0.25-1), python-piston-mini-client:i386 (0.7.5-0ubuntu2), libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil:i386 (4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4), python3-feedparser:i386 (5.1.3-3build1), gnome-menus:i386 (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1), software-properties-common:i386 (0.96.20.7)

How to roll back the results of the autoremove command? Is there is any way to restore Ubuntu 16.04 without reinstalling it?

I am currently logged in to the same machine with an Ubuntu 16.04 live disk.

Comment: when I try to run sudo apt-get install python3-all
then error occur 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct problem

Comment: Do what it says and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem.

Comment: @karel thanks my problem solved successfully.